# Beginning LESS variable values with a period

Tags: css, less

I am using a less variable for CSS namespacing:

```
@search-row-height: 57px;
@namespace: rp-users-;

.@{namespace}search-row {
    height: @search-row-height;
}
```

Is there anyway to put the period inside @namespace's value? Moving it from the beginning of the CSS selector to the beginning of @namespace's value (@namespace: .rp-users-) causes a compilation error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do with escaping:

```
@search-row-height: 57px;
@namespace: ".rp-users-";

@namespaceselector: ~"@{namespace}search-row";
@{namespaceselector} {
    height: @search-row-height;
}
```